# Create new lists from multiple folders and populate them only with the items they contain?

Tags: python, interface

Say I have the following folder structure:

[image]

I already have a list of the Catalogs items:

```
catalogs_list = []

for folder in os.listdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path)):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path, folder)):
        catalogs_list.append(folder)
```

Now, I need to retrieve the subcatalogs but each in a separate list.

```
sub_catalog_list = []
for i in range(len(catalogs_list)):
    for subfolder in os.listdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path, catalogs_list[i])):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path, subfolder)):
            sub_catalog_list.append(subfolder)
```

Problem: The above code puts everything in the same list.

How do I declare a new list each time I have a "Catalog" folder so it appends only its own subfolders? At the end, I want to have the following new lists:

```
catalog_1_items = ["SubCatalog 1", "SubCatalog 2", "SubCatalog 3"]
catalog_2_items = ["SubCatalog 1"]
catalog_3_items = ["SubCatalog 1", "SubCatalog 2"]
```

And then put them in a `master_list`, like so:

```
master_list = [catalog_1_items, catalog_2_items, catalog_3_items]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, for anyone interested:

```
master_list = []                
for i in range(len(catalogs_list)):
    subcatalog_list = []
    for subfolder in os.listdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path, catalogs_list[i])):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(asset_library_path, catalogs_list[i], subfolder)):
        subcatalog_list.append(subfolder)
    master_list.append(subcatalog_list)
```